# How to write a view in couchbase for this sql statement

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

Let's say I have the following documents

```
Document 1
{
  companyId: "1",
  salesDate: "1425254400000" //this is UTC time as a long
}
Document 2
{
  companyId: "1",
  salesDate: "1425340800000" //this is UTC time as a long
}
Document 3
{
  companyId: "2",
  salesDate: "1425254400000" //this is UTC time as a long
}
```

I currently have my view set up as

```
function(doc, meta) { emit([doc.salesDate, doc.companyId], doc); }
```

Which is pulling back all 3 documents when using

```
?startkey=[1425254400000,"1"]&endkey=[1425340800000,"1"]
```

I'm not sure how to make it only pull back the sales for that date range by company id.

The sql version would be SELECT * FROM sales WHERE companyId = :companyId AND salesDate BETWEEN :rangeStart AND :rangeEnd

EDIT: I'm using the rest API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing views for range queries with multiple query fields, the fixed query field(`companyId`) should be a prefix of the compound index and the range query field should be at the end. With the current view, Couchbase will emit every document where `salesDate` is within the range without considering `companyId`.

Reversing the order of keys will work:

```
function(doc, meta) { 
  emit([doc.companyId, doc.salesDate], doc); 
}
```

Query:

```
?startkey=["1", 1425254400000]&endkey=["1", 1425340800000]
```

N.B. if `salesDate` is a string and not a numeric value, Couchbase will use lexicographic ordering to perform the range query.

Comment: That does seem to have fixed it. I swear I tried it like that and it didn't work earlier. Thanks!